# Is it possible to hide / show div based on orientation change javascript / query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

something like:

if orientation = landscape {
hide divA
else
show divA}

excuse non script example, thought it would be easier to explain that way as not too sure the best way to go about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this with css media queries.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/urcxbg8z/) (Make the width of the html view smaller and see what happens)

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) {  
    /* Styles for Portrait screen */  
}  
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {  
    /* Styles for Landscape screen */  
}
```

Comment: Thanks kasper, I was actually looking to have content b replace content a when orientation changed. For instance: opening up a full page navigation menu whilst in portrait and having content in landscape. I see that your answer could work for just hiding stuff but it couldn't work for my example could it?

Comment: yes you can use the same technique. I suggest you read about css responsive designs. There are numerous tutorials online.